# Xcode Scene Dock hidden

Tags: xcode, interface, builder

My scene dock is hidden... How can I make it visible? The red one is missing

[image]

Comment: I updated my question. I hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find this button in below left side just click it

[image]..you will get what you need..

Enjoy..

Comment: @Oskar   i edited my answer just check it...and let me know if any further help you needed..

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what do you mean by scene dock.

But I guess you can see different windows by changing your selection here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if so, Click that **Hide Document Outline** then you ll get that missing window.this is **Hide Document Outline button** [image]

In Xcode you could see the following Menus, **File Edit View Navigate Editor Product Window Help** inwhich Click **View** and click **Debug Area** and then click **Activtae Console**.

You can get the window that what you expect

Comment: Let me know wether your issue sloved or not